# Need a click event parsed to see if link had a certain class then do something

Tags: jquery

So I have a panel that opens and the information on the panel will be different depending on what link they clicked to open it:

html:

```
 <figure>
   <a href="#" id="open-case-study1"> <img src="img/1.png" class="img-responsive gallery-img small-square"/></a>
         <div class="photo-details">
              <a href="#" class="open-case-study1"><i class="icon ion-plus-circled"></i></a>
         </div>
 </figure>
   <a href="#" id="open-case-study2"> <img src="img/2.png" class="img-responsive gallery-img small-square" /></a>
         <div class="photo-details">
              <a href="#" class="open-case-study2"><i class="icon ion-plus-circled"></i></a>
         </div>
 </figure>
 <figure>
   <a href="#" id="open-case-study3"> <img src="img/3.png" class="img-responsive gallery-img small-square"/></a>
         <div class="photo-details">
              <a href="#" class="open-case-study3"><i class="icon ion-plus-circled"></i></a>
         </div>
 </figure>
 <figure>
   <a href="#" id="open-case-study4"> <img src="img/4.png" class="img-responsive gallery-img small-square" /></a>
         <div class="photo-details">
              <a href="#" class="open-case-study4"><i class="icon ion-plus-circled"></i></a>
         </div>
 </figure>
```

Jquery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).html();

    if($(this).hasClass("open-case-study1")) {       
         //do something useful here for now just alert
         alert(link + " 1 was clicked");  
    } else if($(this).hasClass("open-case-study2")) {       
         //do something useful here for now just alert
         alert(link + " 2 was clicked");  
    } else if($(this).hasClass("open-case-study3")) {       
         //do something useful here for now just alert
         alert(link + " 3 was clicked");  
    } else if($(this).hasClass("open-case-study4")) {       
         //do something useful here for now just alert
         alert(link + " 4 was clicked");  
    };
});
```

I googled around and I thought the above would work but it doesn't, clicking an image returns " `<img>` tag info + 1 was clicked" so it's triggered the first if statement. The icons work though.

Comment: Define not working

Comment: @Satpal I got the Icons to work but the images all return:

"                  <img src="img/3.png" class="img-responsive gallery-img small-square"/> 1 was clicked" in the alert.

Answer (score 1):

When are you running your jQuery code?

If the jQuery code is in the `<head>` of your document, your links may not have fully loaded by the time you attach the click handler to your links.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(){
    link = $(this).html();
    if($(this).hasClass("open-case-study1")) {       
         //do something useful here for now just alert
         alert(link + " 1 was clicked");  
    } else if($(this).hasClass("open-case-study2")) {       
         //do something useful here for now just alert
         alert(link + " 2 was clicked");  
    } else if($(this).hasClass("open-case-study3")) {       
         //do something useful here for now just alert
         alert(link + " 3 was clicked");  
    } else if($(this).hasClass("open-case-study4")) {       
         //do something useful here for now just alert
         alert(link + " 4 was clicked");  
    };
  });
);
```

Alternatively, you can run the script at the bottom of the page (under the HTML for all of the links).

When you call `$('a').click(function() { /* ... */ });`, jQuery attaches a click handler to any link already present on the page. JavaScript code is called as the page is rendered, top to bottom. If the script is in the header or included in the header, the browser will encounter your jQuery call before any markup for link tags, and so will not attach a click handler to any of them.

Alternatively, if your script is being loaded using the `src` attribute of the script tag (i.e. you have your HTML and JS in separate files, as is good practice), you can add `defer` to your script tag to prevent the script from running until the page has fully loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js" defer></script>
```

However, some of your users may be using old browsers which do not support this property.

**EDIT:** based on your comment, your issue might be that you expect the class name of the link to be printed out, not the inner html of the link. In that case, try:

```
var link = $(this).attr("class");
```

You'll want to add the right class to the links using an id as well. Or, you can add a class, "open-link" to the outer links, and get them with:

```
var link = $(this).closest(".open-link").attr("id");
```

Also, I would recommend adding `var` before your variable link, unless it is a global variable you are using outside of your function.

Comment: it's in the footer.

I got the Icons to work but the images all return:

"                    <img src="img/3.png" class="img-responsive gallery-img small-square"/>

                      1 was clicked" in the alert.

Comment: Ahh - try changing `link` to `link = $(this).closest("a").html()` - would that work?

Comment: Wait, what are you expecting the output to be in the console logs?

Comment: Because html() returns the inner html for your link, not the markup for the link itself

Comment: nope unfortunately not but it didn't break the icons code either, that still works.

Comment: I don't want the <img> info, I want the <a> ID or Class from the clicked link. I need to detect the "open-case-study" class or ID which is in the <a> tag.

Comment: Try the code in my edit at the bottom - you should be using jQuery's attr function to get attributes of the tag.

Comment: Namely, define link as `var link = $(this).closest("a").attr("id");`

Comment: Dude you rock! That works with the .attr("id")! Only thing weird is the icons now trigger "undefined 3 was clicked" which detects the right icon, but gives undefined, should I be worried that other browsers might not work due to this? 

I believe it's due to my icon links not having an ID.

Comment: Do you know if I could give my icons an id="open-case-study1-icon" and then do something like this in my if statement to detect if they clicked on the img or the icon?

`if($(this).hasClass("open-case-study1, open-case-study1-icon")`

Comment: I would just add a class to all of them instead of relying on ids. If you aren't adding any other classnames to the link, you can get them with $(this).attr("class");